# Django - load object file from template

Tags: static, django-templates, loader

I am trying to load an object file from the template. The template is based on ThreeJs library and I am loading using an object loader, see the code here:

```
loader.load( '{% static "Simu/test.obj" %}', function ( obj ) {
                    scene.add( obj );
                } );
```

The object file *test.obj* is stored in a static sub-folder such as `myStatic/Simu/test.obj`, this is the tree directory of my app:

```
.
├── myStatic
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   └── Simu
│       ├── 0
│       ├── constant
│       │   ├── polyMesh
│       │   └── triSurface
│       └── system
├── pde
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── templates
│       └── pde
├── pdeWeb
│   └── __pycache__
└── static
    ├── admin
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── vendor
    │   │       └── select2
    │   ├── fonts
    │   ├── img
    │   │   └── gis
    │   └── js
    │       ├── admin
    │       └── vendor
    │           ├── jquery
    │           ├── select2
    │           │   └── i18n
    │           └── xregexp
    ├── css
    ├── img
    └── js
```

However, when I run the code it cannot find the file and it gives me this error:

```
Not Found: /pde/{% static "Simu/test.obj" %}
"GET /pde/%7B%%20static%20%22Simu/test.obj%22%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2102
```

It seems it is not going to the static folder at all! it tries to reach a folder named `pde`, why this is happening?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. The loader was not in the html template but in a javascript in the static folder. That was causing the error.